# Truncate a table while preserving the auto increment ID in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a **SQLite** database with several different tables. I want to truncate one of these tables (delete all the rows) while preserving the auto increment ID.

The long way:

```
SELECT id FROM data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 
DELETE FROM data 
ALTER TABLE data AUTO_INCREMENT={value from first query}
```

Is there a shorter/better way?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you created your table with the primary key set to AUTOINCREMENT, then the table will start again with ID of 1.

Please read up more about AUTOINCREMENT in SQLite from here: 
http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe autoincrement keeps the last value by default in MySQL 5 (I recently wanted just the opposite :) So you should be fine just deleting all the rows.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is not MySQL. Also, read about The Truncate Optimization [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html)